# How to protect non-production API Gateway endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

In our previous regular instance-based backends, for a pretty good portion of the development process of the API, we were protecting the dev version of the endpoints with basic auth.

Is there a pattern of how to efficiently hide our serverless endpoints (API Gateway) from public, but still available for the frontend team to develop on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an API key for your non-production API Gateway. A different key from any that you use in production. Give that key to your dev team, then they will be able to call your non-production API Gateway endpoints, while the API will be inaccessible to anyone without the key.

Comment: For those interested, details [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#request-parameters). Look for the "Setting API keys for your Rest API" section.